# Add data from one column to another column on every other row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sgRNA = pd.Series(["ABL1_sgABL1_130854834","ABL1_sgABL1_130862824","ABL1_sgABL1_130872883","ABL1_sgABL1_130884018"])
sequence = pd.Series(["CTTAGGCTATAATCACAATG","GGTTCATCATCATTCAACGG","TCAGTGATGATATAGAACGG","TTGCTCCCTCGAAAAGAGCG"])
df1=pd.DataFrame(sgRNA,columns=["sgRNA"])
df1["sequence"]=sequence

df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=["column"],
                    index=np.arange(len(df1) * 2))
```

I want to add values from both columns from df1 to df2 every other row, like this:

```
ABL1_sgABL1_130854834
CTTAGGCTATAATCACAATG
ABL1_sgABL1_130862824
GGTTCATCATCATTCAACGG
ABL1_sgABL1_130872883
TCAGTGATGATATAGAACGG
ABL1_sgABL1_130884018
TTGCTCCCTCGAAAAGAGCG
```

To do this for `df1["sgRNA"]` I used this code:

```
df2.iloc[0::2, :]=df1["sgRNA"]
```

But I get this error:
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,) into shape (4,1)`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`DataFrame.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack):

```py
df2["column"] = df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
                  column
0  ABL1_sgABL1_130854834
1   CTTAGGCTATAATCACAATG
2  ABL1_sgABL1_130862824
3   GGTTCATCATCATTCAACGG
4  ABL1_sgABL1_130872883
5   TCAGTGATGATATAGAACGG
6  ABL1_sgABL1_130884018
7   TTGCTCCCTCGAAAAGAGCG
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides Andrej Kesely's superior solution, to answer the question of what went wrong in the code, it's really minor:

`df1["sgRNA"]` is a series, one-dimensional, while `df2.iloc[0::2, :]` is
a dataframe, two-dimensional.

The solution would be to make the "df2" part one-dimensional by selecting the
one and only column, instead of selecting a slice of "all one columns", so to
say:

```
df2.iloc[0::2, 0] = df1["sgRNA"]
```